# Getting 404 Error when Trying to Access GraphQL endpoint on Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and working on a demo springboot app using GraphQL. I am looking to access the http://localhost:8080/graphql/schema.json endpoint but getting 404 whitelabel error. I am able to access one of the endpoints in the controller. Initially, I used the springboot graphql maven dependency but included another graphql maven dependency in my pom file but still got 404 error. I will greatly appreciate any help in debugging the error. Below is snippet of my code.

The app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DogGraphqlApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DogGraphqlApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dogdata

graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
graphql.servlet.enabled=true
graphql.servlet.corsEnabled=true

graphiql.enabled=true
graphiql.endpoint=/graphql
graphiql.mapping=graphiql
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

dog.graphqls

```
type Dog {
 id: ID!
 name: String!
 breed: String!
 origin: String!
}

type Query {
 findAllDogs: [Dog]!
 findDogById(id:ID!): Dog!
}

type Mutation {
 deleteDogBreed(breed: String!) : Boolean
 updateDogName(newName: String!, id:ID!) : Dog!
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class DogController {
    private DogService dogService;

    @Autowired
    public void setDogService(DogService dogService){
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/dogs")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Dog>> getAllDog(){
        List<Dog> list = dogService.retrieveDogs();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Dog>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
}
```

Query.java

```
@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    private DogRepository dogRepository;

    public Query(DogRepository dogRepository){
        this.dogRepository = dogRepository;
    }


    public Iterable<Dog> findAllDogs(){
        return dogRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Dog findDogById(Long id){
        Optional<Dog> optionalDog = dogRepository.findById(id);

        if(optionalDog.isPresent()){
            Dog dog = optionalDog.get();
            return dog;

        }else{
            throw new DogNotFoundException("Dog Not Found", id);
        }
    }
}
```

Mutation.java

```
@Component
public class Mutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver {

    private DogRepository dogRepository;

    public Mutation(DogRepository dogRepository){
        this.dogRepository = dogRepository;
    }

    public Boolean deleteDogBreed(String breed){

        boolean deleted = false;
        Iterable <Dog> dogs = dogRepository.findAll();

        for(Dog dog: dogs){
            if(dog.getBreed().equals( breed) ){
                dogRepository.delete(dog);
                deleted = true;
            }
        }

        if(!deleted){
            throw new BreedNotFoundException("Breed Not Found", breed);
        }

        return deleted;
    }

    public Dog updateDogName(String newName, Long id){
        Optional<Dog> optionalDog = dogRepository.findById(id);

        if(optionalDog.isPresent()){
            Dog dog = optionalDog.get();
            dog.setName(newName);
            dogRepository.save(dog);
            return dog;
        }else {
            throw new DogNotFoundException("Dog Not Found", id);
        }
    }
}
```

Error page

[image: Error page]

Comment: What do you get in response to http://localhost:8080/graphql (ie without schema.json)?

Comment: I get the same whitelabel 404 error when I try localhost:8080/graphql. However, if I try localhost:8080/dogs, I get the desired output which is a list of dogs.

Comment: @Othello did you solve the problem? I am also stuck with the same issue (same UD project)